# winPrint.print work only first time use

Tags: javascript, printing

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<input id="print" type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>

</html>


  <script>

   $("#print").click(function () {
                    print();
   });
   function print() {
                var winPrint = window.open('ABC');
                winPrint.document.write('<html><head><title>Title</title></head><body>');
                winPrint.document.write("BODY");
                winPrint.document.write('</body></html>');
                winPrint.document.close();
                winPrint.focus();
                window.stop();

                $(winPrint).on('load', function () {
                    winPrint.print();
                    winPrint.close();
               });



            }
  </script>
```

When I first time click on button print is working but when I click next time on the button print isn't working. Please explain me why when I use `winPrint.document.write('<html><head><title>Title</title></head><body>');` new page all the time is loading and the code `winPrint.print();` is not working.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                winPrint.print();
                winPrint.close();
        });
```

When I used document ready code the result was the same when I had a lot of data in

> winPrint.document.write("BODY");

How can I change my code to work proper?

Answer (score 0):

So, you can't just call `winPrint.close()` after you call `winPrint.print()`. What you ideally want is to provide the user with an option at the bottom of the new window to close the window - this is typically what you'll see across the web. By calling `close()` after `print()`, you run the risk of the window closing before the print dialogue even shows up.

Also, try to limit your `document.write` calls to only one, so place all html you want to put into the new window into a variable.

Take a look at this example below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<input id="print" type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>

<script>

$("#print").click(function () {
   print();
});

function print() {
  var winPrint = window.open("", "ABC");
  winPrint.document.write("<p>Some content</p><p>Some more content</p>");
  winPrint.print();

}

</script>
```

You'll also want to be careful when passing in arguments to the `window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)` function. It takes 4 optional parameters. When you were trying to name your window, you were actually passing in the URL param, which is why it wasn't doing what you want. Just pass in an empty string and it will assume its a _blank window.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<input id="print" type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>

<script>

$("#print").click(function () {
   print();
});

function print() {
  var winPrint = window.open("", "ABC");
  winPrint.document.write("<img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Fronalpstock_big.jpg'></img>");
  winPrint.print();
}

</script>
```

Your code works because in body tag you have small content. Above code shows that print function is called before loading image, because print page is empty.

I wanted use document ready function to call print() when image has been loaded, but it is not work.

How can I change my code to work proper?

Comment: This appears to be a comment on traviswingo's answer. Instead of posting an answer of your own, you should post a comment on his answer. You can also edit your question to clarify it.